# How to create a custom component which having high level ui components in LWUIT-J2ME?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, mobile-application, midp-2.0, cldc

Im developing a mobile application in J2ME with the configuration **CLDC1.1,MIDP2.0** and using **LWUIT**.

Now i want to create a Custom Component (user defined component) which is added in the `Form`,etc (in LWUIT)

Inside the custom component there is 2 `ComboBoxes` and 1 `TextField (com.sun.lwuit.TextField and com.sun.lwuit.ComboBox)`.

I does not know how to do.Because in LWUIT the custom component is derived from `Component` class.But their we need to paint.We cannot able to add the high level UI components such as **`Label`,`TextField`,`ComboBox`**.

So please help me .To create a custom component which having one or more high level UI components (UI components of LWUT like com.sun.lwuit.TextField,com.sun.lwuit.ComboBox,etc).

All are welcome to give their valuable ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea to create your `CustomComponent`in LWUIT is the following.

You can try to create a class wich extends from `Container`, and inside it add the 2 `ComboBox` and the `TextField`. So you can use this "CustomComponent" as a high level UI Component.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot derive MIDP high level UI classes in LWUIT. The whole idea of LWUIT and similar frameworks is abandonment of the broken MIDP API's.